# Move GIF while python pool process is executing in parallel with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gif, concurrent-processing

I want to update the GIF while pool process are executing in parallel. Now GIF is getting stuck, it is responding with respect to progressbar value update. I want GIF to execute independently.  I have tried using it thread but that is not solution for my process. Once control is going to pool-process it getting GUI freeze, not responding. I have given high level piece of code that in this GIF should not stuck. I am copying number of files through process in the original code there it will take much time to complete the task till then GUI gets not responding. So pool-process I can not remove or replace. Let me know if this GIF continuous movement is possible irrespective of progressbar and process executing. I would appreciate code changes because i am new to python and PYQT5.

Thanks in advance.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog,
                             QProgressBar, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

TIME_LIMIT = 100
def func(a, b):
    print(a +b)

class External (QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        print("check1")
        while count < TIME_LIMIT:
            count += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("thread1 update")
            self.countChanged.emit(count)

class Actions (QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.setGeometry(200,300,200,200)
        col = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.text = ['ON', 'OFF']
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.movie = QMovie("movie.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 25)
        self.progress.setMaximum(100)
        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        col.addWidget(self.label)
        col.addWidget(self.progress)
        col.addWidget(self.button)
        self.label.move(0,90)
        self.button.move(0, 30)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        self.show()

    def startAnimation(self):
        self.movie.start()

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.startAnimation()
        self.calc = External()
        a_args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        second_arg = 1
        self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
        self.calc.start()
        QApplication.processEvents()
        for i in a_args:
            pool = Pool(processes=3)
            M = pool.starmap(func, zip(a_args, repeat(second_arg)))
            QApplication.processEvents()
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            print("value of args",i)

    def onCountChanged(self, value):
        self.progress.setValue(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Actions()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, `pool.starmap()` is a synchronous call, even if the `func` work occurs in other processes. You'd need to use `pool.apply_async()` and manually loop and poll for results while `QApplication.processEvents()`ing – or maybe use a timer instead to wait for results, so PyQT remains in control of the event loop.

Comment: (Or, considering you already have that `External` thread, maybe use it.)

Comment: tried both the methods pool.apply_async() and External thread . There is no change in behavior of code functionality. Still getting stuck.

Comment: What did you do with the results of `pool.apply_async()`? Waited for them in a timer loop or external thread?